# detecting long latency in .NET Core PaaS for GCloud

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud, google-cloud-spanner

I am currently experiencing really long latency issues in my .net core 2.2 applications.
The setup consist of an .net API's through the app engine (memory 2g, 1 cpu, resting instance of 2) which talk to spanner tables with indexes. Whenever our system comes under load we tend to get a spike where our instances jump and the latency raises considerably.

On average our request time for an api request is 30ms but this then jumps to 208s even on instances that do not change. The spanner requests are quite short averaging around 0.072502. The just shows a blue bar spanning the whole of the request time. Checking for row locks but these are simply just GET requests and show nothing.

Is there anything else I can look at?

Comment: It may be worth profiling your app to confirm whether this is contention on Spanner and eliminate other possibilities. I've not used Cloud Profiler with .NET (only Go) but there's a library. It does smack of db contention but there's not much detail to your question. https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/cloudprofiler/v2

Comment: And thinking more about it, are you using an API Client Library or Cloud Client Library for Spanner? I assume the latter. Cloud Client Libraries are hand-written It's possible you're hitting a rough edge that's not surfaced in other language SDKs. If it uses gRPC, you could also use Cloud Trace. gRPC libraries are usually automatically instrumented.

Comment: We are using the Google.Cloud.Spanner.Data.dll 2.0.0 nuget library libary to call our spanner database. Passing in SQL text which are purely just simple SQL commands wrapped in a transaction scope. I'm not sure it could be the spanner library as this are all affected together. I will have a look at the profiler. thanks

Comment: Is your number 208 seconds or 208 milliseconds? Add details on your deployment. Define "under load". Which region? The more details the better the chance of an answer. Can you create a duplicate service for load testing? Add profiling to see where the bottlenecks are occurring.